# Move all files in folder but not delete folder in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to know how could I move all files inside a folder (for example: C:\Folder1) to another folder (for example: C:\Folder2), but not delete Folder1 and get how many items have been moved, let me explain;

I need to move all items inside Folder1 (files, folders, sub-folders, sub-files, etc) maintaining directory structure, but without delete Folder1, and if its possible know how many folders and how many files have been moved (only the number of folders and number of files).

Could anybody help me with that?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: If you're moving files and folders but not deleting the originals, you're not moving, you're copying.

Comment: I'm trying to me files and folders, but not delete the folder what contains files and folders, it solved by @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this recursive proc.

```
Public Shared Function moveDirectoryContent(srcDir As String, destDir As String) as Integer
    Dim countFile As Integer = 0
    If (Not Directory.Exists(destDir)) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir)
    End If
    Dim listFiles() As String = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(srcDir)
    Dim curFile As String

    For Each curFile In listFiles
        If Directory.Exists(curFile) Then
            countFile = countFile + moveDirectoryContent(curFile, Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(curFile)))
        Else
            Dim dstFile = Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(curFile))
            If File.Exists(dstFile) Then
                dstFile = GetUniqueName(dstFile)
            End If
            File.Copy(curFile, dstFile)
            File.Delete(curFile)
            countFile = countFile + 1
        End If
    Next
    Return countFile
End Function


Public Shared Function GetUniqueName(srcFile as String) as String
    Dim uFile As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(srcFile)
    Dim ext as String = Path.GetExtension(srcFile)
    Dim cnt As Integer = 0
    Dim uniqueText = string.Format("_{0}_00", DateTime.ToDay.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd"))
    While(File.Exists(uFile + uniqueText + ext))
        cnt = cnt + 1
        uniqueText = string.Format("_{0}_{1:D2}", DateTime.ToDay.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd"), cnt)
    End While
    Return Path.GetDirectoryName(srcFile) + "\" + uFile + uniqueText + ext
End Function
```

and call in this way

```
numMoved = moveDirectoryContent("C:\temp", "C:\temp2")
```

Beware, the destination folder cannot be inside the source folder.... (no check performed)

Comment: Is there any way to not overwrite files, I mean if file exist change name of new file, if folder exist overwrite but not files inside, the point is combine folders but not overwrite files, just change name and move it, is there any way?

Comment: Answer updated, added a new method the generate an unique file in the destination folder insted of delete the file already present.

Comment: It not found this function: "moveDirectory" in that part: "countFile = countFile + moveDirectory(curFile, Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(curFile)))" I think I should change for this: "moveDirectoryContent" but not works, if file exist inside destiny folder, only do is delete it, any idea?

Comment: But not works, it only delete file, not rename file and move it if exist on destiny folder, it just delete it (or move overwritting, I'm not quite sure), any idea?

Comment: @MySelf Allright, time to start VS and start a little debug. Try now

Comment: It works but with a little change: in function "GetUniqueName", change this line: "While(File.Exists(uFile + uniqueText + ext))" for this other "While (File.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(srcFile) + "\" + uFile + uniqueText + ext))" and it worked perfect!, thanks a lot :)